# Installing a 3rd party dll in C:\windows folder - Is this ok?

Tags: windows-10, security, dll

Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=5LvC_UaEhvA&t=8s

Third party app called as algomojo installs its DLLs in C:/windows folder. Personally, I always thought touching windows os folder is not a good practice. However, the developer (algomojo) claims

[Response of developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAJHV.png)

I would like to know right/best practices and if algomojo's installation could potentially harm the windows OS folders in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s unnecessary. There is absolutely nothing else I can say about putting a file in the Windows folder. It’s completely and totally unnecessary, the developer is completely and totally lying about the reasons the file is being installed to that directory, or they’re completely incompetent.

Comment: Perhaps a better fit for https://security.stackexchange.com/ The reason given does not make any sense. The fact that a file is inside or outside the windows folder does not affect latency. AlgoMojo is probably a scam.

Comment: https://www.caclubindia.com/forum/retail-algo-trading-scam-details-578275.asp People lose lots of money on AlgoMojo so its probably best not to touch it.   Quote:  "They later launched "advanced, high-tech, server-based " platform called Algomojo for trading. This software allowed server based algo trading without any supervision at all. As an "icing on the cake", they provided several trading strategies. I gradually lost Rs. 8 lakh in trading over next 4 months with Algomojo, additional to the course fee of 1.2 lakh."

Comment: If it sounds too good to be true, it probably isn't true.